# Ruby ./src/postgres/include/port/atomics.h:68:10: fatal error: 'port/atomics/arch-arm.h' file not found

Tags: ruby, postgresql, apple-m1

Receiving this error when attempting to install `pg_query -v '1.0.2` gem on ruby 2.6.6 on an M1 Mac.

Here's the full trace:

```
In file included from src/pg_query_json_plpgsql.c:2:                                                                                                                            
In file included from src/pg_query_json_plpgsql.h:5:                                    
In file included from ./src/postgres/include/plpgsql.h:21:                              
In file included from ./src/postgres/include/commands/trigger.h:17:                                                                                                             
In file included from ./src/postgres/include/nodes/execnodes.h:17:                      
In file included from ./src/postgres/include/access/genam.h:19:                         
In file included from ./src/postgres/include/nodes/tidbitmap.h:26:                      
In file included from ./src/postgres/include/utils/dsa.h:17:                            
./src/postgres/include/port/atomics.h:68:10: fatal error: 'port/atomics/arch-arm.h' file not found                                                                              
#include "port/atomics/arch-arm.h"                                                      
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~                                                      
1 error generated.            
make: *** [src/pg_query_json_plpgsql.o] Error 1                                         
cp: directory ./../../spec/files does not exist                                         
creating Makefile                                                                                                                                                               
                                                                                                                                                                                
current directory: /Users/tonybeninate/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6@ammoready-two-point-oh/gems/pg_query-1.0.2/ext/pg_query                                                             
make "DESTDIR=" clean                                                                   
                                                                                                                                                                                
current directory: /Users/tonybeninate/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6@ammoready-two-point-oh/gems/pg_query-1.0.2/ext/pg_query    
make "DESTDIR="                                                                                                                                                                 
compiling pg_query_ruby.c
pg_query_ruby.c:23:1: warning: function 'raise_ruby_parse_error' could be declared with attribute 'noreturn' [-Wmissing-noreturn]                                               
{                                                                                                                                                                               
^                                    
pg_query_ruby.c:41:1: warning: function 'raise_ruby_normalize_error' could be declared with attribute 'noreturn' [-Wmissing-noreturn]                                           
{                                                                                       
^                                                                                       
pg_query_ruby.c:59:1: warning: function 'raise_ruby_fingerprint_error' could be declared with attribute 'noreturn' [-Wmissing-noreturn]                                         
{                                                                                       
^                                                                                       
3 warnings generated.                                                                   
linking shared-object pg_query/pg_query.bundle              
ld: library not found for -lpg_query                                                                                                                                            
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)         
make: *** [pg_query.bundle] Error 1
                                                                                        
make failed, exit code 2                                                                
                                                                                                                                                                                
Gem files will remain installed in /Users/tonybeninate/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6@ammoready-two-point-oh/gems/pg_query-1.0.2 for inspection.                                          
Results logged to /Users/tonybeninate/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6@ammoready-two-point-oh/extensions/-darwin-20/2.6.0/pg_query-1.0.2/gem_make.out                                       
                                                                                                                                                                                
An error occurred while installing pg_query (1.0.2), and Bundler cannot continue.       
Make sure that `gem install pg_query -v '1.0.2' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For posterity, I had to upgrade to `pg_query` 1.3.0 in order to get ARM support. https://github.com/pganalyze/pg_query/issues/210